# pgfplotstable: How to create rows with a loop

Tags: pgfplotstable, foreach, loops

I want to create several table-rows with calculated data inside. 
So I think, I have to use `\pgfplotstablevertcat{<1>}{<2>}`

But something like this (example!) does not work:

```
\foreach \k in {1,...,5}{
\pgfplotstableread{
\k \pgfmathparse{\k^2}\pgfmathresult
}\dataX % How to name this best way?
}
```

What have I to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
This works:
% Data
\pgfplotstableread[]{
1 1
}\data

\pgfplotstableread{
2 4
}\dataII

% Concatenate
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\data}{\dataII}
% Output
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns/0/.style={column name=$k$},
columns/1/.style={column name=$k^2$}
]{\data}

This does not work: 
%\foreach \k in {1,...,5}{
%\pgfplotstableread{
%\k \pgfmathparse{\k^2}\pgfmathresult
%}\dataX % How to name this best way
%}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for `create on use` (or `\pgfplotstablecreatecol`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

This is how it works:
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/k/.style={
create col/set list={1,...,10}},
columns/my new col/.style={string type}}
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/ksquared/.style={
create col/assign/.code={
\getthisrow{k}\entry
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynewentry}{\entry*\entry}%
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\mynewentry}}}
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={k,ksquared}]{10}\cistable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/k/.style={column name=$k$},
columns/ksquared/.style={column name=$k^2$}]{\cistable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mmh, I understand. So I think, I can work with this. Thx. ;)