# pgfplotstable: How to use \pgfplotstablevertcat in a loop

Tags: pgfplotstable

I know there are [other options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518612/46023) too.

But I was wondering:
*How can I create one-row tables in a loop and then add them to the previous total table?*

In the following attempt, only the current loop value is accepted.

How can I fix this? 
*I am particularly interested in using the `\pgfplotstablevertcat` function for this.* 
Is this possible?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}
\section{Create following Table row by row}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[header=true, col sep=comma]{
k, 2k
1, 2
2, 4
3, 6
} 


\section{Try}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false, col sep=comma]{
k,    2k
}{\main}

Startsituation: \pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\main} 

\subsection{Loop}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \k in {1,2,3} {%%
\pgfmathsetmacro\Double{2*\k}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false, col sep=comma, 
row sep=\\ % <--- seems that he wants that............
]{
\k, \Double \\
}{\temp}

\noindent Temprow (good!): \pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\temp} 

\pgfplotstablevertcat{\main}{\temp} 
\noindent Tempsituation (bad!): \pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\main} 
}%%
\end{document}
```